# Reverse foreign key sets for a model view

Tags: django, orm

Wih the following model setup:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    claw = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Fur(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Cat)

    class Meta:
        db_table=u'cat_view'
        managed=False
```

[image: example]

Fur has a foreign key to Cat. CatView is a subset view of Cat that is being managed manually. Is there a way to make use of django's useful reverse set methods with this setup?

Additionally, I could just use Fur.objects.filter(cat_id=cat_view.id, ...) which would be the same functionality as cat_view.fur_set.filter(...), however I could not do reverse lookups such as CatView.objects.filter(fur__type="shaggy").

EDIT:
Added example models file, changed image for clarity, added minor complexity to question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, neither of those ORM calls you give will work: `fur_set` is an attribute of a `cat` instance, not of the `Cat.objects` Manager.

Secondly, Django has no specific support for database views *at all*, so your question about using this particular bit of functionality with a view is a bit strange. You *could* define CatView as a separate (unmanaged) model, although you'd need to be careful about updating and saving. Then you can get the same effect as the reverse relation by querying the `Fur` object directly:

```
Fur.objects.filter(cat=my_cat_view.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I edited my question and the image. I am manually managing a view and you can see what additional functionality I need that cannot be done by querying on the Fur object directly.